# How does face group work?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm very confused about the documentation because in order to call the endpoint `/group` you need faceIDs.
Thus if you want to have faceIDs you need to through face `/detect`.

But a faceIDs is available for 24h only:

> The faceId will expire 24 hours after detection call.

Thus, does it mean that each time I need to analyse people in a batch I have to make twice the call, first to identify the face and then for the group?
I assume we can't have 'both in one'.

Answer (score 1):

The id from /detect is ephemeral, you need to add the faces to a person in a group and train the group. You can then use the service to identify people by their faces.